# OpenAI gym and Python threading

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am working on a variation of A3C/ACER and I have several workers, each running on its own thread. I am using OpenAI gym environments.

Python threading works fine but it cannot fully utilize all cores. As there are no blocking I/O, it does not context switch.

I would like workers to somehow to release the GIL while executing actions in their respective environments.

I would appreciate your feedback: Does it make sense and it is possible?

Comment: maybe this helps: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/583, also: have you run the profiler?

Comment: Thanks! However, my question is more about threading and OpenAI gym. I dont think I am affected by that old performance issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question: I found that a quite efficient way is demonstrated in OpenAI universe-starter-agent: https://github.com/openai/universe-starter-agent.

The implementation uses Tensorflow and runs independent processes including a parameter server.

I think this can be useful as a reference to other people too.